# эффект *перетяните картинку сюда* каким способом можно сделать?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, файлы

```
<div class="dashed_1">
                <input onchange="readURL(this)" class="cool_inp" id="img" type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
                <label class="pseudolabel" for="img"><b>+ Загрузить</b></label>
                <p>Или перетяните картинку сюда</p>
            </div>
```

есть например код, надо чтоб в пределах блока класса dashed_1 если на него перетянуть изображение то чтоб оно загрузилось как через кнопку.. Как можно реализовать? как отследить такое событие?

Comment: Drag and Drop API, 
File API, 
Canvas/Image API, 
fetch\web socket

Comment: https://habr.com/post/136694/ уже пережевали это

Comment: @МаксимЛенский прочитал статью, но не вышло сделать так как хотел, не нашел - как привязать поле, куда перемещается файл к инпуту - чтоб когда файл отпускали - он вызывал *change* в определенном инпуте и вставлял в него файл

Comment: в самом верху написано по порядку - от 1 до 4 нужно применить всё ...я только с 4 пунктом не уверен - так как делал просто так - балуясь